# Why 304 result getting instade of 200 when website is loading?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I developed one application for www.smetiger.com
Whhen I open or load the web application and go to network traffic capturing, hitting shift + f5 
the Result tab shows **304 instead of 200**

What is the reason the resultcode is **304**?

Is the 304 response result making my website slower?

Comment: Why don't you look up [what 304 means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_304#3xx_Redirection) and you can probably answer the "is it making my website slower" question yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The response that you get is `304 Not Modified`.

That means that the browser already has the resource in the cache, and asks the server if there is a newer version of it. The server answers by saying that there is no newer version, so the browser should use the version that it already has.

This makes the website faster, not slower. The response from the server is just the header, the server doesn't have to send the content again as the browser already has it.

Answer (score 2):

An error code 304 means that the page was not modified since your last request.
It doesn't slow down your page. In contrary, when a statusCode 304 is returned, the browser uses the data which is already in cache.
You can read about that behaviour in the [http 1.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.5).

To analyze your website you can use the developer tools. If you're using Safari or Chrome the [Developer Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/index) are available. For safari the developer tools are documented on the [apple page](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007874-CH1-SW1).
In Firefox you can install the AddOn [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

[image]

Comment: Firefox has its own developer tools too... although Firebug has existed since antiquity, Firefox has had native developer tools for a while.

Comment: Yep, that's true. But the network tool used to be horrible. With their newest redesign in Firefox 29 they also refactored the developer tools. It looks pretty good now (though pretty similar to chrome).